# How to install all packages of "Priority: standard" on Debian

Tags: debian, amazon-web-services, installation

When installed from DVD, a new Debian installation has a lot of packages.  I've become used to having mutt, vim, etc. installed by default.

However, AWS AMIs and debootstrap installations have only a minimal set of packages installed (less than 300) which is not a bad thing if you're setting up a server to only do a few things, but if you actually want to log into the host regularly and *use* it, having to install basic packages all the time is a pain.

How do I tell Debian to install all packages of "Priority:  standard" from the repository?

Answer (score 4):

Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo tasksel --new-install
```

And make sure you turn off/on any options you do or don't want.

It will then scan the list of packages and install all available that have "Priority:  standard".

If it fails with an error indicating that dpkg failed, try running the second command again.  It worked for me the second time around.

Comment: I've had issues on and off with this method. this is by far the briefest and easier to memorize option however it doesn't seem to reproduce very well on various debian releases

Answer (score 1):

with aptitude

```
apt update
apt install -y aptitude
aptitude install '?priority(standard)'
```

(I would like to find an option that didn't rely on aptitude)